# How to add 2 integer inputs rather than joining them in python

Tags: python

i was making a program to add the numbers of two given input but the number am giving they are getting joined instead of getting added, below is my code.

```
print("enter 1st no.")
no1 = input(int())

print("enter 2nd no.")
no2 = input(int())

print (int(no1 ++ no2))
```

i putted 1 and 2 in the input and am getting result as 12 instead of 3 please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Use `int(input())` not `input(int())`:

```py
print("enter 1st no.")
no1 = int(input())

print("enter 2nd no.")
no2 = int(input())

print(no1 + no2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
No1 = int(input())
No2 = int(input())

print(No1 + No2)
```

Comment: `Print()`, really?

Comment: Sorry, typing with phone and thus capitalized ;) print()

Comment: You can fix it, please also format the answer correctly, and add some context on *why* this is the solution and how this is different from the answer already posted.

Comment: I suggest to follow the naming conventions from the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions), so `No1` and `No2` should be `no1` and `no2` (or even better `number1` and `number2`).